# QMediaPlayer and Segmentation Fault

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, audio-player, qmediaplayer

Hello Guys i used just this simple example to play music with this code:

```
QMediaPlayer *mediaPlayer { new QMediaPlayer };
mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl(currentMediaFileName));
mediaPlayer->setVolume(50);
mediaPlayer->play();
```

he show me in debug mode the message "Segmentation fault" and my application crash.

I used Qt 5.15.0

Comment: I've checked your piece of code, it ran without problem (Qt 5.12). Maybe your problem is from somewhere else.

Comment: did you used my code ? or your code ? try it into Qt5.15.0

Comment: I used your code.

Comment: I thought that my code had some problems but if you open the Qt example "media player"  and you launch it neither the videos nor the audio works. He show the error "DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 ()"

Comment: install Qt5.15.0 and Qt 4.13.0 and you will see. if the problem is general or it only me.

Comment: I too am having this problem, i'm using PyQt 5.15. `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

**This seems to be a bug in Qt. I found [*this bug report*](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89796). Hopefully this issue will be resolved soon.**

---

Based on my experience, the problem seems to occur only on certain hardware: I have two laptop computers, both with XUbuntu 21.04 and both using proprietary drivers, and when running the same code i get `SIGSEGV` on one system but on the other (older) system there is no problem.